# Express app only working on local machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a simple API for a project. I have ran the following sample code on two machines, using Postman for testing. When the code is running on my machine, I will get a response; However, when the code is running on a remote ubuntu server, the server will not get the request.

I have tried restarting the remote server.
Edit: I have tried sending requests with IPv6.
`http://[<ipv6 of server>]:8080/api/test`

```js
const app = express();
const api = express.Router();
const port = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', api);

api.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log("I got a request!");

    res.send("Hello!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

When I send an example POST request and express is running on my machine:
`http://localhost:8080/api/test` will respond and print `I got a request!` to the console.

When I send an example POST request and express is running on a remote ubuntu server:
`http://<ipv4 of server>:8080/api/test` will not respond and nothing is printed to the console.

Could not find a solution. Used a different remote server and it worked.

Comment: Are you able to ping your remote server from the other machine?

Comment: @PrerakSola I am.

Comment: if you can call `http://localhost:8080/api/test` from the ubuntu server itself then this is a pure network/firewall issue

Comment: Have you tried sshing into the remote server and hitting it locally from there. If it works locally on the remote machine then you know its a connection/firewall issue and you should check the open ports using iptables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was having a similar problem. I think it's something related to firewall settings.
Try to deactivate firewall and see if you can make the requests.
It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

try using different port like 3000 or etc

8080 may be commonly used port , it may be used by some other process on server

check using `lsof -i:8080` will list all processes running on 8080 port

Comment: Nothing else is running on 8080.

Comment: The process would fail if the port was taken.

Comment: Have You checked for port blocking? Maybe 8080 port is blocked by default